# How can I scroll listitems up and down inside a div using click?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to build a simple list of itens and make them scroll inside by clicking on next or prev arrows. I didn't want to use any plugins cause i think that is very simple but i'm not abble to make them scroll 3 itens at time or scroll just the height pixels.

Somebody can help me?

[Fiddle Here](http://bit.ly/1i5MnbD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

`.movies-list{display:block;height:620px;overflow:hidden}`

and remove

`div.section-movies ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 2000px;
}`

then add some jQuery

```
//get li height
var gh = $('.movies-list li').eq(0).height();
//prev
$('.movie-prev').on('click', function() {
    var cs = $('.movies-list').scrollTop();
    if (cs>gh) {
        cs = cs-gh;
    } else {
        cs = 0;
    }
    $('.movies-list').animate({scrollTop: cs});
});
//next
$('.movie-next').on('click', function() {
    var cs = $('.movies-list').scrollTop();
    cs = cs+gh;
    $('.movies-list').animate({scrollTop: cs});
});
```

something similar to this should work, you may have to tweak the value of `gh` depending on how everything else is set.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/4Gb4x/

Comment: hi, i want to scroll but using click on the itens prev and next :)

Comment: Cool, I've updated the answer and fiddle to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Inside

```
.window-movies {
```

add:

```
max-height:400px;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

but this simple solution will break your footer. I guess you will need js for that.

EDIT:

```
$('.movie-next').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            bottom: 0
        });
```

Add this to your js to keep your footer at the bottom.

Comment: max-height:400px; is just an example